# FFmpeg: read an input link from a text file directly (without extra tools and pipes)

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

There is the text file - link.txt. That file contains the following link to the video:

```
$ cat link.txt
https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4
```

I can transcode the video from that file in the next way:

```
ffmpeg -i $(cat link.txt) -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac out.mpg
```

or I can use pipe to achive the same result:

```
cat link.txt | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac out.mpg
```

But I have to run FFmpeg via specific software and it doesn't support pipes and commands above. 
**I'm looking a solution to run FFmpeg like this:**

```
ffmpeg -some-extra-parameters -to-say-ffmpeg -get-the-link \
       -from-the-text-file -i link.txt -vcodec libx264 \
       -acodec libfdk_aac out.mpg
```

**Question 1:** Is that feature implemented in FFmpeg?

Also, I checked [FFmpeg presets](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Preset-files)
and created the FFPRESET file for my goal:

```
$ cat /usr/local/share/ffmpeg/linkpreset.ffpreset
i=https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4
vcodec=libx264
acodec=libfdk_aac
```

I got the error when I tried to execute FFmpeg with that preset:

```
$ ffmpeg -fpre /usr/local/share/ffmpeg/linkpreset.ffpreset out.mpg

/usr/local/share/ffmpeg/linkpreset.ffpreset: Invalid option or argument: 
'i=https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4', 
parsed as 'i' = 'https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
```

**Question 2:** Is there way to specify input link in a FFPRESET file? 
**Question 3(main):** How to read an input link from a text file in FFmpeg directly(without extra tools and pipes)?

Comment: Do you control the text file?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, I control the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct method to do this, but a workaround is to use the concat demuxer with a single entry.

Create a text file containing

```
file 'https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i link.txt ...
```